# How can I make a site with 1.300.000 pages?

Tags: apache

Yeah I know, it's not a joke.....I really need some advice on how I could create a web site which could handle 1.300.000 ref. or more

Currently I'm running a dedicated server with 2mo ram and 1.6 proc, with a drupal 7 install and mysql 5.1, but the database keeps crashing and the load of the server is really awful!!! I was looking into an Apache Solr solution but still don't see how it will resolve my problem

I tried some solution with full xml page (no databases) or just html but nothing is working...I'm probably missing something here, but what, I can't see!!!

Does anyone have some light to shade on my problem?

Comment: That's a lot of pages to run in your own server. Have you considered hiring a hosting solution? Most of them don't have a bandwidth limit.

Comment: @Renan if you use more that 5+% of their processing capabilities, some "unlimited" hosts are going to say that is too much and suspend your account.

Comment: Thanks @Renan, but @Christofian is right, I can't use a hoting solution, furthermore my database flies around 9-10 Go and hosting provider limit theirs to 200 Mo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need four things: your own VPS, nginx with php-fpm (Apache is a resource-hog), and lots of caching. If you're running Drupal, there must be some static caching plugins available. Static caching will reduce DB queries (which you want to do in most cases). Memcache is also an alternative.

For this, I'd recommend hiring an expert!

Comment: Thanks Matty,You just confirmed what I was doing lol, I was playing with varnish/nginx/php-fpm and everything is running better now

Answer (score 0):

It depends how much traffic these 1.3m pages are getting. If it's a high-traffic site, I expect you'll be looking at a dedicated database server and another to handle 'the rest'...

More info.

Comment: Yep, that's sounds like a part of the solution, I hope to make it a high traffic, but currently it's a miracle if I can serve 600 by day with a load of 20.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a solution with only static html/xml pages and no database involved, as the content will rarely change. Using Google CSE as a search engine, I tried on my local system but I had to reboot the whole system :(

Comment: Using static pages as opposed to a database requires a lot less processing power since whatever you're planning to use as a server won't have to query a database - which can be resource intensive depending on how well it's all put together. For serving static pages, all the server needs to do is serve a pre-generated page rather than generating dynamic pages, so effectively, you can have a site with as many pages as your hdd can facilitate. Then what spec the server is depends on the traffic, it's as simple as that.